# Scroll raton no funciona en Expander WPF . Net

Tags: wpf

estoy teniendo problemas con el scroll de raton en una aplicacion WPF dentro de un control Expander.
Mi codigo es el siguiente, pero he probado muchos otros y no consigo que funcione, el scroll del raton solo funciona si tengo el puntero en el propio scroll, y no en el GridView que tengo dentro del Expander.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Steel.Tabs"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Steel.Tabs"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="700">
<Grid>
    <Expander Name="epAsciiTable" Header="ASCII Table" IsExpanded="True" Margin="4,0,4,20" MinWidth="700" Initialized="epAsciiTable_Initialized" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ListView Name="lvAsciiTable1" Margin="0,8,0,0">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True">
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Decimal" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding dec}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Hexadecimal" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding hx}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Octal" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding oct}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Char" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding chr}"/>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Expander>
</Grid>
```

Solo puedo hacer funcionar el scroll con las teclas Flecha arriba y Flecha abajo (para subir o bajar) pero el scroll deja de funcionar fuera del propio scroll.viewer.
Necesito que funcione dentro de todo el control Expander.

Gracias

¿Alguien podría decirme donde esta el problema?